# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lists'

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, parent

I created a class, something like below -

```
class child:
    def __init__(self,lists):
        self.myList = lists
        
    def find_mean(self):
        mean=np.mean(self.myList)
        return mean
```

and when I create an onject something like below -

```
obj=child()
```

it gives the error -

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lists'
```

if I create object like below then it works well -

```
obj=child([44,22,55)
```

or If I create the class like below -

```
class child:        
    def find_mean(self,myList):
        mean=np.mean(myList)
        return mean
```

and then I create the object like below -

```
obj=child()
```

then also it works well, however I need to make it in the way I explained in the very begining. Can you please help me understand this context?

Comment: Your second example doesn't define `__init__` with an additional parameter. You've just shifted the need for an argument to `obj.find_mean(...)`.  I don't know where your confusion lies.

Comment: What do you want `obj.myList` to be if you say `obj=child()`?

Comment: thankyou both --- I want to create my class like this class child:
    def __init__(self,lists):
        self.myList = lists
        
    def find_mean(self):
        mean=np.mean(self.myList)
        return mean and the object like this obj=child()

Comment: sorry I'm new here hence strugling with the post formating

Comment: @SameerVerma that doesn't answer the question: **what do you want myList to be if you never provide a `lists` argument?**  What list of numbers do you want to return the `mean` of when you call `find_mean`?  Just pasting your (non-working) code again doesn't add any clarity.  It's very clear why it doesn't work; you have to clarify what you want it to do if anyone is going to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the `__init__` method expects two parameters:

- `self` is automatically filled in by Python.
- `lists` is a parameter which you must give it. It will try to assign this value to a new variable called `self.myList`, and it won't know what value it is supposed to use if you don't give it one.

In the second example, you have not written an `__init__` method. This means that Python creates its own default `__init__` function which will not require any parameters. However, the `find_mean` method now requires you to give it a parameter instead.

When you say you want to create it in the way you explained at the beginning, this is actually impossible: the class requires a value, and you are not giving it one.

Therefore, it is hard for me to tell what you really want to do. However, one option might be that you want to create the class earlier, and then add a list to it later on. In this case, the code would look like this:

```py
import numpy as np

class Child:
    def __init__(self, lists=None):
        self.myList = lists
        
    def find_mean(self):
        if self.myList is None:
            return np.nan
        mean = np.mean(self.myList)
        return mean
```

This code allows you to create the object earlier, and add a list to it later. If you try to call `find_mean` without giving it a list, it will simply return `nan`:

```py
child = Child()
print(child.find_mean())  # Returns `nan`
child.myList = [1, 2, 3]
print(child.find_mean())  # Returns `2`
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you have at the top of your question defines a class called `child`, which has one attribute, `lists`, which is assigned at the time of instance creation in the `__init__` method. This means that you must supply a list when creating an instance of `child`.

```py
class child:
    def __init__(self, lists):
        self.myList = lists
        
    def find_mean(self):
        mean=np.mean(self.myList)
        return mean

# works because a list is provided
obj = child([44,22,55])

# does not work because no list is given
obj = child()  # TypeError
```

If you create the class like in your second example, `__init__` is no longer being explicitly specified, and as such, the object has no attributes that must be assigned at instance creation:

```py
class child:        
    def find_mean(self, myList):
        mean=np.mean(myList)
        return mean


# does not work because `child()` does not take any arguments
obj = child([44,22,55])  # TypeError

# works because no list is needed
obj = child()
```

The only way to both have the `myList` attribute, *and* not need to specify it at creation would be to assign a default value to it:

```py
class child:        
    def find_mean(self,myList=None):
        mean=np.mean(myList)
        return mean


# now this will work
obj = child()

# as will this
obj = child([24, 35, 27])
```